# MySQL - join query to include unmatched records

Tags: mysql, select, mariadb, inner-join

I'm learning MySQL and I couldn't find a solution to this problem.
I have three tables:

`Companies`:

| CompanyID (PRIMARY KEY) | EntryDate | CompanyName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 2000-01-01 | foo |
| 13 | 2000-01-02 | bar |

`CompaniesAndFunds`:

| Company |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 23 |

`NatureOfCompanyDefs`:

| NatureOfCompanyID (PRIMARY KEY) | NatureOfCompany |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | foo |
| 88 | bar |

How can I modify this query so the result will also include unmatched records, I mean - include "Companies" without assigned "Nature":

```
SELECT
    Companies.EntryDate,
    Companies.CompanyName,
    NatureOfCompanyDefs.NatureOfCompany,
    CompaniesAndFunds.Company 
FROM
    CompaniesAndFunds
    INNER JOIN Companies ON CompaniesAndFunds.Company = Companies.CompanyID
    INNER JOIN NatureOfCompanyDefs ON Companies.NatureOfCompany = NatureOfCompanyDefs.NatureOfCompanyID
```

Comment: use `LEFT JOIN` in stead of `INNER JOIN` ?

Comment: And switch the order of joins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using an inner join instead of a Left Join. Inner Joins will exclusively show matches, whereas left will show even unmatched rows. Try:

```
SELECT
    Companies.EntryDate,
    Companies.CompanyName,
    NatureOfCompanyDefs.NatureOfCompany,
    CompaniesAndFunds.Company 
FROM
    CompaniesAndFunds
    INNER JOIN Companies ON CompaniesAndFunds.Company = Companies.CompanyID
    LEFT JOIN NatureOfCompanyDefs ON Companies.NatureOfCompany = NatureOfCompanyDefs.NatureOfCompanyID
```